# insert fail in a table that have composite key in Doctrine-symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

when i insert in a table that has composite key of two fields , it fail and say it is null insertion , once i delete the composite key it insert successfully.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO course_to_category (courseId, categoryId, ordering) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, 1]:
```

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'courseId' cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your composite key is primary key. Check this:

> A PRIMARY KEY is a unique index where all key columns must be defined as NOT NULL. If they are not explicitly declared as NOT NULL, MySQL declares them so implicitly (and silently). A table can have only one PRIMARY KEY. The name of a PRIMARY KEY is always PRIMARY, which thus cannot be used as the name for any other kind of index.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: yes it is primary key for 2 fields and my app need that so please help me how to insert with that case

Comment: @AhmedGroup why do you need a row with 2 `null`s and `ordering=1`? Maybe you should adjust your logic?

Comment: i dont enter null , i enter  3 values but due to presence of composite key he assume them as nulls as these 2 fields form a composite key , once i deletge the key the values are inserted